# Code Coverage for every (different) input data

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I want to get the Code Coverage of some simple test, which gets data from a DataProvider. I need the coverage result for each data that runs through the test. For example:

```
if (value != 0)
{
   //do something
}

if (value == 100) {
   //do something
}
   //else do something
```

If the test gets a value like 0 from the DataProvider, it never reaches the first part of the code, so the coverage result is different than if the value was 100.
**So how do I get those coverage results for each data?** I am using jacoco with the maven plugin...

It maybe would help, if there is a possibility to run the subtests with maven... Currently I am doing this:

```
mvn test
```

but I want to do something like this:

```
mvn -Dtest=myTestClass#myTest#myData (#myData of course not working)
```

However IntelliJ uses this parameter to specifiy the subtest:

```
java.exe -ea [.......] @name0 //-> to run the test only with first Data
java.exe -ea [.......] @name1 //-> to run the test only with second Data
etc.
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code coverage is the percentage of code which is covered by automated tests. Code coverage measurement simply determines which statements in a body of code have been executed through a test run, and which statements have not. 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/clover/about-code-coverage-71599496.html

You can pass the arguments from command line and then run your tests.
You can pass them on the command line like this

```
mvn test -Dtest=<ClassName> -Dvalue=100
```

then access them in your test with

```
int value=Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("value"));
```

Comment: Thank you!! Dont forget to add 'test' at the end: mvn -Dtest=<ClassName> -Dvalue=100 test